# Accessing DOM element with namespace in Freemarker template

Tags: dom, freemarker

I have the following XML

```
<wmi xmlns="http://www.exmple.com/XMLSchema/fulfillment/v1/order/orderShipment" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/XMLSchema/fulfillment/v1/order/orderShipment OrderShipmentNotification.xsd">
<wmiHeader>
    <fileID>693401.20160229.130342.3541254</fileID>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <messageType>FSN</messageType>
    <genDate>2016-02-29T13:03:42Z</genDate>
    <from>
    </from>
</wmiHeader>
<orderShipNotification>
    <shipmentHeader dateTimeCreated="2016-02-29T13:03:42Z" requestNumber="2574445351883" />
    <shipmentDetails actualShipmentDateTime="2016-02-29T12:18:54Z" carrierCode="XX" carrierMethodCode="XX-01">
        <shipmentPackDetails trackingNumber="9361289672090007124848" trackingURL="https://example.com/go/TrackConfirmAction_input?qtc_tLabels1=323434">
            <shipmentPackLineDetails requestLineNumber="1" partnerItemID="FXT-CC-LB" itemQtyShipped="1" />
        </shipmentPackDetails>
    </shipmentDetails>
</orderShipNotification>
</wmi>
```

I am getting error in Freemarker template when I am trying to access.

```
${orderShipNotification.shipmentDetails.@actualShipmentDateTime[0]!""}
```

If I delete the namespaces from the document it is working fine. I deleted the following content from the XML

```
xmlns="http://www.exmple.com/XMLSchema/fulfillment/v1/order/orderShipment" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/XMLSchema/fulfillment/v1/order/orderShipment OrderShipmentNotification.xsd"
```

I did some investigation. The is a ftl directive. But it is still not clear how this will solve the problem. Please let me know how I can access the attributes.

```
 http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_ftl.html#ref.directive.ftl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the template with

```
<#ftl ns_prefixes={"D":"http://www.exmple.com/XMLSchema/fulfillment/v1/order/orderShipment"}>
```

This sets the namespace as the default (`D` stands for default). Note that if you will also use XPath queries, there you will have to write out the `D:` before the element names (this is an XPath restriction).

This is documented here: http://freemarker.org/docs/xgui_imperative_learn.html